# How to convert text to a number vector to use it in classifier algorithm?

Tags: vector, text

I need to classify texts to 2 categories. For this purpose I will use phpml library and KNearestNeighbors/SVC/MLPClassifier classifiers algorithm. Here are the link to one of them https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/machine-learning/classification/k-nearest-neighbors/.  To use such algorithm i need to convert every text to a vector and after that supply this vector as a parameter to train the algorithm.

I understand that i need to do the following steps:

1. Tokenize every text. So text -> word list
2. Use language stemmer for each word from the list. At this stage I have a list of stemmed words in a text
3. Build a dictionary of all words from all texts.

What should I do next? What is the dimension of each vector?
How do i build correct vector to supply it for classifier algorithm?
May be there is a library to vectorize text in php?

Thanks a lot